# Не появляются данные пользователя Джанго

Tags: python, django

Страница работает. После авторизации я перехожу на главную страницу, но фио не появляется в виде текста. Все сделанно правильно, но все равно ничего не появляется

views.py

```html
def account(request): 
    return render(request, 'logistic/account.html', {
        'personali': Personal.objects.filter(fio = request.POST.get("fio"))
    })
```

account.py

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}Личный кабинет{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'logistic/css/account.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <div class = "body">
        <img src = "{% static 'logistic/image/1900/1900-background.png' %}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="window"></div>
    <form action= "" method="POST">
        {% for account in personali %}
        <td id="header-name-services">{{ account.fio }}</td>
        {{ account.date }}
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```html
    path('account/', views.account, name='account'),
```

models.py

```html
class Personal(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) #ключевое
    fio = models.CharField('ФИО', max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Дата рождения')
    username = models.CharField('Логин', max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField('Пароль',max_length=100, unique=True)
```

forms.py

```html
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personal
        fields = ['fio', 'date', 'username', 'password']

        widgets = {
            "fio": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'fio_input',

            }),
            "date": DateInput(attrs={
                'id': 'date_input',
                'type': 'date',

            }),
            "username": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'login_input',

            }),
            "password": TextInput(attrs={
                'id': 'password_input',
                'type': 'password',

            }),
           
            
        }



class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'login_input_autho',}))
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'password_input_autho','type': 'password',}))

    class Meta:
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции account у вас отсутствует проверка на метод запроса

views.py

```
def account(request): 
    personali = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fio = request.POST.get('fio')
        personali = Personal.objects.filter(fio=fio)
    return render(request, 'logistic/account.html', {
        'personali': personali
    })
```

account.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}Личный кабинет{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'logistic/css/account.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "body">
        <img src = "{% static 'logistic/image/1900/1900-background.png' %}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="window"></div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Введите ФИО">
        <button type="submit">Поиск</button>
    </form>
    {% if personali %}
        {% for account in personali %}
            <td id="header-name-services">{{ account.fio }}</td>
            {{ account.date }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</body>
</
```

Добавлен тег {% csrf_token %} внутрь формы, а также в форме поиска вы добавляете поле ввода ФИО и кнопку "Поиск".